# Splitting a date string within a Nested List to group lists by the month - Python

Tags: python, date, filter, nested

This is a homework assignment. I am not allowed to use libraries etc. The purpose is to learn and understand nested lists, loops and filtering by conditionals in Python.

I have a nested list of data, a short extract is below. It is 200 lines long.

```
patients = [ ['Milos', 'Jones', '15/01/20', 'male', 'smoker', '210'],
             ['Delia', 'Chan', '15/03/20', 'female', 'non-smoker', '170'],
             ['Denise', 'Ross', '13/02/20', 'female', 'non-smoker', '150'] ]
```

I need to be able to filter the list by gender and the month.
Convert the [5] element in each list to an integer ready.

To filter by gender I have written this code:

```
female_patients = []
for solo_patient in patients:
    if solo_patient[3] == 'female':
        female_patients.append(solo_patient)
```

I have converted the element to an integer using :

```
for solo_patient in patients:
    solo_patient[5] = int(solo_patient[5])
```

Both work and output what I need.

However, I am trying to split the data into strings and convert to integers so I can filter by month. I used similar logic to above but I can't make it work properly.

```
for solo_patient in patients:
patients[2] = [solo_patient[2].split('/')
```

This gives me an error " IndexError: list index out of range"

If I use the code:

```
for solo_patient in patients:
patients = [solo_patient[2].split('/')
```

It splits the date into "MM", "DD", "YY" but I lose the other data.

When I do get it split, I need to convert the date strings into integers, then using a loop for range(1,13) go through and group by the month. Then I need to perform basic statistics on the data for male/female. I think I know how to do that once I have filtered the lists correctly. I would appreciate any advice, explanations or constructive feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let me tell you what you're doing wrong here -

```
for solo_patient in patients:
    patients[2] = solo_patient[2].split('/')
```

here's in each for loop call i.e 0,1,2. You're trying to update the last row -> patients[2].

patients[2] = ['Denise', 'Ross', '13/02/20', 'female', 'non-smoker', '150']

patients[2] value will change if you do something like this inside for loop.

Let's do this instead -

```
for solo_patient in patients:
    print((solo_patient[2]).split('/'))
```

The above statement will give you another list -

```
['15', '01', '20']
['15', '03', '20']
['13', '02', '20']
```

Now, if you wanna assign this value back to the original list at a specific index i.e 2 of each row. you can do something like this

```
for index,solo_patient in enumerate(patients):
    patients[index][2] = tuple((solo_patient[2]).split('/'))
    
print(patients)
```

This will print -

```
[['Milos', 'Jones', ('15', '01', '20'), 'male', 'smoker', '210'],
 ['Delia', 'Chan', ('15', '03', '20'), 'female', 'non-smoker', '170'],
 ['Denise', 'Ross', ('13', '02', '20'), 'female', 'non-smoker', '150']]
```

To Extract months.

```
month_list= [] #initialize empty list
for solo_patient in patients:
    date = solo_patient[2].split('/') # split and create list
    month_list.append(int(date[1])) # select the value at index 1 and convert it to int and then append it to month list.
    
print(month_list)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this explanation. Now I can see where I was going wrong. In the code above how do I access the month string in the tuple?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution to group patients by month:

```
patients_by_month = {month: [] for month in range(1, 13)}
for patient in patients:
    mm = int(patient[2].split('/')[1])
    patients_by_month[mm].append(patient)
```

I you run this code over your example then `patients_by_month` is:

```
{1: [['Milos', 'Jones', '15/01/20', 'male', 'smoker', '210']],
 2: [['Denise', 'Ross', '13/02/20', 'female', 'non-smoker', '150']],
 3: [['Delia', 'Chan', '15/03/20', 'female', 'non-smoker', '170']],
 4: [], 5: [], 6: [], 7: [], 8: [], 9: [], 10: [], 11: [], 12: []}
```

Specifically, `patients_by_month` is a dictionary that maps each month to a list of patients.

Comment: When I try to run your code I get an error "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: @EmBass I think you have some errors within your data. For example, are you sure ALL your patients have 5 fields and ALL your patients have a date with DD,MM,YY?

Comment: @EmBass Please provide some data on which my code does not run properly so that I can help you

Comment: I am sorry. It seems it was me. It is working now.

Comment: @EmBass Please mark my answer as accepted if you think it was useful :)